# If or Piecewise dependent coefficients in NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, conditional

This:
[image]

but the following (placing the partials inside the If) does not. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Usually better to write a (mathematical) function with `Piecewise` instead of `If`, although steps were taken to mitigate users' use of `If` in some contexts. And it's much better to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so others can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them to test their ideas and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: Same thing happens with Piecewise, i.e.,  ```u = NDSolveValue[{D[\[CapitalTheta][t, x], t] - Piecewise[{{0.00093, x < 0.4}}, 0.05405]*
        D[\[CapitalTheta][t, x], x, x] == 0, \[CapitalTheta][0, x] == 300, \[CapitalTheta][t, 0] == 300, \[CapitalTheta][t, 1] == 400}, \[CapitalTheta], 
    {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> 
       "FiniteElement"}];```

Comment: vs  ```u = NDSolveValue[{D[\[CapitalTheta][t, x], t] - Piecewise[{{0.00093*D[\[CapitalTheta][t, x], x, x], x < 0.4}}, 
        0.05405*D[\[CapitalTheta][t, x], x, x]] == 0, \[CapitalTheta][0, x] == 300, \[CapitalTheta][t, 0] == 300, 
     \[CapitalTheta][t, 1] == 400}, \[CapitalTheta], {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"}]; ```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to "place the derivatives inside the If"? You expect it to get the same result as what you have working, right? So why is it that you want to change it?

Comment: These are the heat transfer equations for a two-layer composite, constant diffusivity in each layer. Yet, next step, one of the layers is a smart material for which thermal diffusivity is a function of temperature thus for this case it has to be inside the If statement. Another user commented in a subsequent post that the problem is with the use of "FiniteElement" and suggested to remove it. This yields a solution is different than the one above with the derivatives outside the If, and I do not yet know which one is correct! Thank you for your comment, and any suggestions will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples in the documentation that show how to do this: Have a look at the nonlinear (single material) model on the [HeatTransferPDEComponent ref page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeatTransferPDEComponent.html#1634499991). Concerning multi-materials you could have a look at the [Shring Fitting Model](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/ModelCollection/ShrinkFitting.html). Generally speaking, if you are looking for ideas on how to model something it a good step to open the guide page for that particular field of physics. In this case the guide page for the [Heat Transfer PDEs and Boundary Conditions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HeatTransferPDEModels.html). On that guide page you will find a section "Models Overview" that contains a list of the application models and what 'features' they have. For example, if they are a multi-material model. Note that the guide page only links to the more elaborate application models. So it is advisable to also check out the ref page of the PDEComponent that you are interested in.